# What are some of the : codes for CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If you didn't understand my question- im asking what are some other CSS codes like `:hover`, like different things you would put into the `:`part. I tried searching it up, but cant find much, so I would appreciate if somebody could help me.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a number of pseudo-classes that you can use, either for links, identifying content and in CSS3, determining outputs.

They can all be found here: [Advanced CSS Selectors - Pseudo Classes](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#Pseudo-classes)

- `:link` - the normal, default state of links, just as you first found them.
- `:visited` - selects links that you have already visited in the browser you are currently using.
- `:hover` - selects links that currently have the keyboard cursor within them.
- `:focus` - selects links that are currently being hovered over by the mouse pointer.
- `:active` - selects links that are currently being clicked on.
- `:not()` - selects elements that are not matched in the braces
- `:lang()` -  selects elements whose languages have been set to the specified language using the lang attribute.
- `:target` -  select an element if it is the target of the current page URL.
- `:valid` - HTML5 - form valid
- `:invalid` - HTML5 - form invalid
- `:enabled` - HTML5 - form field enabled
- `:disabled` - HTML5 - form field disabled
- `:root` - elements based on their position in the document hierarchy.
- `:nth-child()` - selects elements that match within the braces
- `:first-child` - selects the first element within a selector
- `:last-child` - selects the last element within a selector
- `:first-letter` - selects the first letter of text
- `:first-line` - selects the first line of text
- `:before` - element to specify that content should be inserted before
- `:after` - elements to specify that content should be inserted after

Also, don't forget about double colon syntax. Note that the new CSS3 way of writing pseudo-elements is to use a double colon, eg `a::after { ... }`, to set them apart from pseudo-classes. You may see this sometimes in CSS. CSS3 however also still allows for single colon pseudo-elements, for the sake of backwards compatibility, and we would advise that you stick with this syntax for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

These are called CSS [pseudo-classes](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#Pseudo-classes) and include:

- :link
- :visited
- :focus
- :hover
- :active

Answer (score 1):

The anchor  tags should be in this order:

- a:link
- a:visited
- a:hover
- a:active

Or as they teach in school, **L**o**V**e / **HA**te to remember it next time you have to code the  tags out.

Other than those ones, there's pseudo selectors like :first-child, :last-child as well as :before and :after which is used a lot.

Find more examples here: https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

They are called pseudo classes: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't know what they were :P

Answer (score 0):

You mean pseudo-classes. There is a list here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp